# How to save an array into a text file with a format f10.0?

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numpy import *
savetxt(txtfilename,ndarr,fmt='?')
```

If I have a number **6.5**, I want to save it in a format such that it will become **00000006.5** . I am not sure whether this kind of format is called  f10.0 but I supposed that here first. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I have tried to use a format which is '%10.0f' but it doesn't work.

So what kind of format should I enter so that the format f10.0 can be achieved?

Thank you for your help.

**UTC+8:00 2014-03-24 11:55AM**

Thanks for the answering from joel, it works.

And I would like to share a indirect method that I used.

```
data_fmt=array([['{0:010}'.format(i) for i in j] for j in data_csv])
savetxt(os.path.join(metpath,'data_fmt.txt'),data_fmt,fmt='%s',delimiter='')
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: That method, using .format, doesn't always add a decimal point and a fractional digit to the output; e.g.

    `'{0:010}'.format(6500)` gives
    `'0000006500'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "%010.1f". This will work in your specific example:

```
>>> '%010.1f' % 6.5
'00000006.5'
```

A leading flag of 0 is needed to format a float so it's padded with leading zeroes.